# Write in / Update an existing Json File

Tags: json, react-native

I'm making an app where i have a list of bills stored in a JsonFile. When i'm connected in the app, i'm redirected to the view which contains the list of all bills that are in my JsonFile (Picture, name, etc...)

No problem for that. I have two more views, when I click on a row, i'm redirected to the view of the bill's description, there, i can change values and click on "Edit".

How can I edit my bill inside the JSon File ? (And add a bill when I want to create a bill in the JsonFile ?)

**EditView Render**

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center'}}
    style={[Styles.container, {height: this.state.visibleHeight}]}>
    <View style={Styles.form}>
      <View style={Styles.row}>
        <Text style={Styles.rowLabel}>Produit</Text>
        <TextInput
          ref='billType'
          style={textInputStyle}
          value={billType}
          editable={this.state.editable}
          keyboardType='default'
          returnKeyType='next'
          autoCapitalize='none'
          autoCorrect={false}
          onChangeText={this.handleChangeBillType}
          underlineColorAndroid={this.state.underline}
          autoCorrect={false}
          placeholder={billType} />
      </View>
      <View style={Styles.row}>
        <Text style={Styles.rowLabel}>Créancier</Text>
        <TextInput
          ref='billCreditor'
          style={textInputStyle}
          value={this.state.billCreditor}
          editable={this.state.editable}
          keyboardType='default'
          returnKeyType='next'
          autoCapitalize='none'
          autoCorrect={false}
          onChangeText={this.handleChangeBillCreditor}
          underlineColorAndroid={this.state.underline}
          placeholder={billCreditor} />
      </View>

<View style={[Styles.loginRow]}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={Styles.loginButtonWrapper}
          onPress={this.handlePressEditable.bind(this)}>
          <View style={Styles.loginButton}>
            <Text style={Styles.loginText}>Editer</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={Styles.loginButtonWrapper} onPress={this.goBack.bind(this)}>
          <View style={Styles.loginButton}>
            <Text style={Styles.loginText}>Supprimer</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
```

**Some things that i found**

I saw that there is AsyncStorage but I don't know how to really use it. 
Also there is react-native-fs, if it's usefull or what i would like an concrete example if it's possible, because the documentation is not explicit enough for my case i think.

Is someone can help me with that please?

Thanks for all !

Comment: AsyncStorage is the ideal place to store application state on disk. Does each bill have a unique id? If you absolutely must export to json as a requirement/feature, then react-native-fs would be the route i'd take. Read into JS object, do your editing, and JSON.stringify the entire dataset to file.

Comment: Ok thanks ! I will give it a try ^^